# How can I do this search db.collection.find( { foo: /^bar$/i } ); on mongo but using Mongo Java Driver

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, case-insensitive, mongodb-java

I 'm trying to make a case insensitive query in mongodb using java driver. I have a string for example "abcdef" in a field named foo when I search for "abc" the search must return empty, but it always return the element that contains "abcdef".

If I do this in mongo console

```
db.collection.find( { foo: /^abc$/i } )
```

it works and it returns nothing. not return the object containing "abcdef", if we have an object with foo:"abc" it only returns one

But in java driver I have tried.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("foo",  "^"+abc+"$");
query.put("$options", "i");
```

and

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("foo", Pattern.compile("/^"+abc+"$/",
              Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: User the Java Regexp object or use BSON `{ "foo": "$regex"  `{ "$regex": "^abc$" } }`. Both work just as well.

Comment: Thanks, we use also this DBObject inClause = new BasicDBObject("$regex", "abc").append("$options", "i");
       BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("foo",inClause); and this returns all containing the string "abc" and we only want to return just "abc" or "ABC" not "abcdef"

Comment: Well of course it does. Because you omitted the `^` caret at the start as I advised. That anchors matches to the "start" of the string. Much as people would have advised is you used the regex tag on the question in the first place. And `$` means "end of string" or you can use `\b` for a word boundary. This is a regex question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pattern like `^(abc)` E.g.

```
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("^(abc)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```